# Iterating through a XML document with multiple subnodes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a difficult time looping through nodes of an XML document. 
I have a document that has the following hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEMPONDERZOEK xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<TRIES>3</TRIES>
<RESULTATEN>
   <INSTRUMENT>
      <INSTRUMENT_CODE>SPOTCHEM EZ</INSTRUMENT_CODE>
      <TEST_CODE>0</TEST_CODE>
      <VLAG>1</VLAG>
      <ANALYSES>
         <ANALYSE>
            <AFKORTING>BUN</AFKORTING>
            <WAARDE>23.7</WAARDE>
            <EENHEID>MMOL/L</EENHEID>
         </ANALYSE>
         <ANALYSE>
            <AFKORTING>GLU</AFKORTING>
            <WAARDE>15.0</WAARDE>
            <EENHEID>MMOL/L</EENHEID>
         </ANALYSE>
      </ANALYSES>
   </INSTRUMENT>
   <INSTRUMENT>
      <INSTRUMENT_CODE>SPOTCHEM EL</INSTRUMENT_CODE>
      <TEST_CODE>1</TEST_CODE>
      <VLAG>1</VLAG>
      <ANALYSES>
         <ANALYSE>
            <AFKORTING>Na</AFKORTING>
            <WAARDE> 152</WAARDE>
            <EENHEID>mmol/L</EENHEID>
         </ANALYSE>
         <ANALYSE>
            <AFKORTING>K</AFKORTING>
            <WAARDE> 4.4</WAARDE>
            <EENHEID>mmol/L</EENHEID>
         </ANALYSE>
      </ANALYSES>
   </INSTRUMENT>
</RESULTATEN>
</TEMPONDERZOEK>
```

I have written the following C# code to iterate through the document:

```
 // Get all fraudulent XML files
        string[] fraudulentsArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"tempXML\fraudulent", "temp_*.xml");

        // Iterate through every XML file that has been collected
        foreach (var x in fraudulentsArray)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(x);

            // Get the first parent node
            XmlNode resultaten = xml.SelectSingleNode("//RESULTATEN");

            // Get all the INSTRUMENT nodes in RESULTATEN
            var instrumentNodes = resultaten.SelectNodes("//INSTRUMENT");

            // Loop through the instrument nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < instrumentNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get the values from nodes inside parent node INSTRUMENT and store them
                xmlanalyse.INSTRUMENT_CODE = instrumentNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                xmlanalyse.TEST_CODE = instrumentNodes[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText.ToInt();
                xmlanalyse.VLAG = instrumentNodes[i].ChildNodes[2].InnerText.ToInt();

                // Get the ANALYSES parent node
                XmlNode analyses = instrumentNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//ANALYSES");

                // Get all the ANALYSE nodes in parent node ANALYSES
                var analysesNodes = analyses.SelectNodes("//ANALYSE");

                // Loop through the ANALYSE nodes
                for (int j = 0; j < analysesNodes.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Store them..
                    ANALYSE tempresultaat = new ANALYSE();

                    tempresultaat.AFKORTING = analysesNodes[j].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                    tempresultaat.WAARDE = analysesNodes[j].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                    tempresultaat.EENHEID = analysesNodes[j].ChildNodes[2].InnerText;

                    xmlanalyse.ANALYSES.Add(tempresultaat);
                }

                onderzoek.RESULTATEN.Add(xmlanalyse);
            }
        }
```

The problem I have with this loop is that it does not make the distinction between the INSTRUMENT nodes. The result of this is that in the first loop I get all the values from ANALYSE from the first INSTRUMENT node but I also get the values from ANALYSE from the second INSTRUMENT node. This also happens in the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to indicate the current context (just a `.`) on your XPATHs expressions:

```
var instrumentNodes = resultaten.SelectNodes(".//INSTRUMENT");
var analyses = instrumentNodes[i].SelectSingleNode(".//ANALYSES");
var analysesNodes = analyses.SelectNodes(".//ANALYSE");
```

Ideally, you could get rid of all those `//` and use the default current context:

```
foreach (XmlElement instrument in xml.SelectNodes("//INSTRUMENT"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(instrument.SelectSingleNode("INSTRUMENT_CODE").InnerText);

    foreach (XmlElement analyse in instrument.SelectNodes("ANALYSES/ANALYSE"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(analyse.SelectSingleNode("AFKORTING").InnerText);
    }
}
```

Another suggestion is to avoid the `ChildNodes[n]` syntax, as your code will break if the XML file changes. Consider the "AFKORTING" example above.

Are you trying to transform the XML file into business objects? Did you tried [deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) it?